# setOnClickListener() on a null object reference error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

My Problem: application not starting.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
method 'void
android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
on a null object reference
        at info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)

Main activity line 25 , rellay_timeline.setOnClickListener(new
View.OnClickListener() {
```

**MainActivity.java** class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    RelativeLayout rellay_timeline;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Button btnSimpleTabs, btnScrollableTabs, btnIconTextTabs, btnIconTabs, btnCustomIconTextTabs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rellay_timeline = findViewById(R.id.rellay_timeline999);

        rellay_timeline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_Timeline.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btnSimpleTabs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSimpleTabs);
        btnScrollableTabs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScrollableTabs);
        btnIconTextTabs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIconTextTabs);
        btnIconTabs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIconTabs);
        btnCustomIconTextTabs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCustomIconTabs);

        btnSimpleTabs.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnScrollableTabs.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnIconTextTabs.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnIconTabs.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCustomIconTextTabs.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSimpleTabs:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SimpleTabsActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.btnScrollableTabs:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScrollableTabsActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.btnIconTextTabs:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, IconTextTabsActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.btnIconTabs:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, IconTabsActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.btnCustomIconTabs:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomViewIconTextTabsActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is `xml` file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.ScrollableTabsActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="372dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rellay_timeline999"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorBitterSweet"
                android:clickable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_archary"
                    android:tint="@color/colorWhite" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="@color/colorBitterSweetDark"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Stok Transferi"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_timeline

```
public class Activity_Timeline extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}
}
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508258/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-widget-button-setonclicklistener?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Where is your remaining button which you initialised after this error? Are you sure you are using correct layout file?

Comment: app has stopped error, If I delete the click command everything works.

Comment: The XML file that you provided here, is it `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: activity_main.xml menu link

Comment: Please goto your res/layout/ find the directory activity_main and delete the activity_main.xml(v23)

Answer (score 0):

You should cast layout to Relative Layout. I want to suggest to write like this

```
 rellay_timeline = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rellay_timeline999);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is a RelativeLayout component , or the id you are finding is in the same View you are setting the content view .

Answer (score 0):

There seems nothing wrong with the code and xml.
Are you sure, the xml is the activity_main.xml? Because it says

> tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.ScrollableTabsActivity"

If you're sure you're using the right layout file, you can try to clean and rebuild the project. Sometimes the generated `R` class gets messed up and then ids are wrong and that strange errors can occur.

EDIT

Another possible reason (from Mohammed Ali's posted link) would be, that you have different layouts for different API levels (e.g. in layout-v23) that is used when you run the app and that is different to the default layout.

Comment: thank you for answer but no solition