# findViewById() must not be null when creating a custom toast

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following function that display a custom toast

```
fun showCustomToast() {
        val inflater = layoutInflater
        val container: ViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.toastContainer)
        val layout: ViewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, container) as ViewGroup
        val text: TextView = layout.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        text.text = "This is a custom toast"
        with (Toast(applicationContext)) {
            setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0)
            duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            view = layout
            show()
        }
}
```

I am calling this function on main activity just below  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`When running the application I am getting the following error

> 

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> findViewById(R.id.toastContainer) must not be null
```

What am I doing wrong  . . .
I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851505/android-kotlin-findviewbyid-must-not-be-null) but it doesn't help

Comment: Does this (R.id.toastContainer) id actually exists?

Comment: Yes, it exists! IllegalStateException error is a runtime, It would have failed to compile if toastContainer did not exist @PrajwalW

Comment: Try cleaning up your project

Comment: In which layout is `toastContainer` in?

Comment: R.layout.custom_toast @laalto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> val container: ViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.toastContainer)
> val layout: ViewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, container) as ViewGroup
> ```

In your comments you write `toastContainer` is in `custom_toast` layout. It cannot be found in the current layout (assuming it's an activity).

You don't actually need a container for inflater, and since the toast is not yet showing there wouldn't be any real container available anyway yet. You can replace these two lines with something like

```
val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `findViewById()` will search for views within your Activity's layout and not any other specific views you might have declared.
Is your container inside another `View`?

Comment: I have a layout for activity and different layout for toast . . . So how can I set custom toast from main activity