# Whenever i run android studio, this is what appears (AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main)

Tags: android-studio

Whenever i run my program on android studio, this is appears

AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4288
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

```js
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button AddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
        AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText FirstNum=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstNum);
                EditText SecondNum=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.SecondNum);
                TextView Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);

                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(FirstNum.getText().toString());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(SecondNum.getText().toString());
                int result = num1 + num2;

                Result.setText(result + " ");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.Addbutton)` returns `null`, which means, it can't find a view with that id in your current layout. So make sure your `activity_main` layout contains an element with id `AddButton` and that it is indeed a `Button`

Answer (score -1):

Look that your error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object
```

so this link may help you solve this problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508258](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508258/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-widget-button-setonclicklistener)

To avoid this error, you should use databinding instead