# LogCat said I attempted to invoke a virtual method on a null object

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm currently trying my hands on a project and encountered this problem. I wanted to make the title in the toolbar to change according to whichever tab was selected and encountered this problem. I've learned JavaScript for around 1 to 2 weeks now and not sure what to do. So, I've looked it up online and learned that it means the object I'm referencing is "empty", thus null. Reading other posts I understand I need to initialize the variable after declaring. The problem is I've attempted to initialize the null objects, which are tabDevices, tabSyncActivity and tabSettings (Example tabDevices = new TabItem() ), but it also wants me to enter two parameters called Context (Which I kinda understand but still not sure what to put it in) and AttributeSet (Which I still don't know what it means)

The MainActivity:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private TabItem tabDevices;
private TabItem tabSyncActivity;
private TabItem tabSettings;
ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 0);


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.tabDevices:
            toolbar.setTitle(viewPageAdapter.getPageTitle(1));
            break;
        case R.id.tabSyncActivity:
            toolbar.setTitle(viewPageAdapter.getPageTitle(2));
            break;
        case R.id.tabSettings:
            toolbar.setTitle(viewPageAdapter.getPageTitle(3));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarClipBridge);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpagerClipBridge);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayoutClipBridge);

    tabDevices = findViewById(R.id.tabDevices);
    tabSyncActivity = findViewById(R.id.tabSyncActivity);
    tabSettings = findViewById(R.id.tabSettings);


    fragmentDevices fragmentDevices = new fragmentDevices();
    fragmentSyncActivity fragmentSyncActivity = new fragmentSyncActivity();
    fragmentSettings fragmentSettings = new fragmentSettings();


    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(fragmentDevices, "Devices");
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(fragmentSyncActivity, "Sync Activity");
    viewPageAdapter.addFragment(fragmentSettings, "Settings");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);


    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_devices_24);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_sync_24);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_24);


    tabDevices.setOnClickListener(this);
    tabSyncActivity.setOnClickListener(this);
    tabSettings.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

I also have another class called ViewPageAdapter but I don't think it's related to the problem at all since I didn't use the setOnClickListener method whatsoever in that class

The LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.clipbridge.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

Comment: `<TabItem>`s don't end up as actual `View`s in the hierarchy, and their IDs aren't assigned to anything there, so `findViewById()` will return null for them. To listen for tab clicks, you instead want to set an `OnTabSelectedListener` on the `TabLayout`. Have a look here: https://material.io/components/tabs/android#using-tabs.

Comment: Btw, this is [java], not [javascript].

Comment: Also, you've got an extra `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` line. You should remove the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned XML Check whether you have matching IDs in both Java and XML or your content view must be not binded either.
for more refer [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508258/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-widget-button-setonclicklistener)